# Linear isomorphisms with dense graph

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is it true that for each infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ there exists a linear bijection $f: X \rightarrow X$ with a dense graph?

A graph of $f$ it is the set $\Gamma(f):=\{(x, f(x)): x \in X \} \subset X \times X$.

($X\times X$ is a Banach space with natural addition and multiplication by scalars and norm defined by $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ for $x,y \in X$.)

It seems that it is true when $X$ is separable.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean with dense image?

Comment: @Robert: dense image would be trivial.

Comment: @Willie: Of course, just wanted to be sure.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the answer would follow from applying the answer you got for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60057/1543), by considering a bijection between two different Hamel bases.

Comment: Is the term "graphic" standard? Actually, "graph" sounds a little better to me. Also, perhaps you can add the definition of the graph of $f$ into the question text itself.

Comment: @WillieWong, why don't you post this as answer?

Comment: @Norbert: go ahead if you feel like it. It being two years on I will have to re-read both questions, that answer, and try to solve the hint I left...