# A linearly independent, countable dense subset of $l^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does there exist a linear independent and dense subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60057/does-there-exist-a-linear-independent-and-dense-subset)

I am looking for an example of a countable dense subset of the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ consisting of linearly independent vectors

Comment: You might want to begin by accepting answers. See [why](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) and [how](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287).

Comment: If $l^2$ are real sequences, is the set of square summable rational sequences not dense in it?

Comment: I missed "linearly independent".

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60057/does-there-exist-a-linear-independent-and-dense-subset/60109#60109.  In my answer there, I show that any separable Banach space has such a subset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Davide's answer.  Begin with the set $\{x_n\}$ of vectors with only finitely many nonzero coordinates, all rational.  That is dense, but not linearly independent.  Next choose a sequence (say $2^{-n}, n=1,2,\dots$) that goes to zero.  Add $2^{-n}$ to coordinate $r_n$ of $x_n$, chosen so that $r_n > r_{n-1}$ and the $r_n$ coordinate of all $x_k, 1 \le k \le n$ is zero.  This new sequence is still dense, but also linearly independent.

Comment: That's a nice explicit example.