# On the Equivalent Norms for Subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

By a function space I mean a vector space of functions.

Assume that $M$ is a function spaces which $\|\cdot\|_{X}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{Y}$ are defined such that
\begin{align*}
\|f+g\|_{X}&\leq\|f\|_{X}+\|g\|_{X}\\
\|af\|_{X}&=|a|\|f\|_{X}
\end{align*}
but with the possibility that $\|f\|_{X}=\infty$ for $f\in M$. Of course $\|\cdot\|_{Y}$ also bears these properties.

Now let $X$ and $Y$ be such that $\|f\|_{X}<\infty$ and $\|f\|_{Y}<\infty$ respectively for $f\in M$, so both $\|\cdot\|_{X}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{Y}$ are norms on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Assume further that a subspace $D$ is such that $\overline{D}^{X}=X$ and $\overline{D}^{Y}=Y$ and we have 
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{X}\approx\|f\|_{Y},~~~~f\in D
\end{align*}
in the sense that 
\begin{align*}
c^{-1}\|f\|_{Y}\leq\|f\|_{X}\leq c\|f\|_{Y},~~~~f\in D
\end{align*}
where the constant $c>0$ is independent of $f\in D$.

Initially I was thinking that if $X=Y$. Note that $f\in X$ only satisfies that $\|f\|_{X}<\infty$ but could be $\|f\|_{Y}=\infty$ and vice versa.

If $X=Y$, then whether it is necessarily that
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{X}\approx\|f\|_{Y}.
\end{align*}
But actually this seems need no to be the case.

For the second concern, suppose $f\in X$ and $f_{n}\in D$ are such that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{X}\rightarrow 0$, we wish to show that $\|f\|_{Y}\leq C\|f\|_{X}$, this will imply at the same time that $\|f\|_{Y}<\infty$.

At first we have 
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{X}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{n}\|_{X}\geq c^{-1}\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{n}\|_{Y}.
\end{align*}
But one cannot assert immediately that 
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{n}\|_{Y}\geq\|f\|_{Y}.
\end{align*}
And of course $\|f_{n}-f\|_{X}\rightarrow 0$ says nothing about the convergence of $\|f_{n}-f\|_{Y}$.

**Philosophy:** Initially I have a philosophical view that two norms are equivalent on a dense subspace, then they should also be equivalent on the space, which is just a slightly larger than the dense subspace, but I think that my philosophical view is not accurate.

Therefore I am looking for counterexample.

At least, can we say that $X=Y$ as sets? Note that $X=Y$ need no implies $\|\cdot\|_{X}\approx\|\cdot\|_{Y}$.

Comment: As answered by Slup, you can't have $X=Y$. But what you actually can have is $||\cdot||_X \approx ||\cdot||_Y$ on $X \cap Y$.

Comment: Given norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces I believe at the very least we need to consider infinite dimensional spaces for a counterexample. Not sure which ones will work yet.

Comment: This is roughly the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482895/8157).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a slight variation on the answer given by Slup. Consider $\ell^{2}$, let $e_{i}$ be standard orthonormal basis and consider the space
$$X=\{x\in\ell_{2}:x=\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}e_{i}\text{ where }n\in\mathbb{N},\ x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
the set of all finite sums of standard basis vectors. Note that $X$ is a subspace of $\ell^{2}$. Let $C$ be a linear subspace of $\ell_{2}$ such that $\ell_{2}=X\oplus C$, such a space exists due to Zorn's lemma. Consider the norm $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\ell_{2}$ given by
$$\|x+c\|=\|x\|_{2}+\|c\|_{3}\qquad(x\in X,c\in C).$$
Note that $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ and $\|\cdot\|$ are equivalent, indeed equal, on $X$, but $\overline{X}^{\|\cdot\|_{2}}=\ell_{2}$ and $\overline{X}^{\|\cdot\|}=X$.

Comment: I rewrite the confusing part of my question, then it seems that you are answering a slightly different question than mine? Of course, your answer is still very interesting.

Comment: I might not have completely understood your question. (Technically there actually is no question.) What I have shown is that the closure with respect to one norm can be significantly different to the closure of the other norm. Also clearly on the whole space the two norms are not equivalent. If you want to find a space with two non-equivalent norms which are equivalent on a dense subset, (sense with respect to both norms,) then I will have to put my thinking hat on again.

Comment: It is an excelent question by the way.

Comment: Actually the unedited answer by @Slup, the first part of his answer, may be what I am looking for. Note that in my question, certainly $\|f\|_{X}$ need no to be finite for every $f\in M$. Rather, for those are finite, $X$ collects them.

Comment: Okay, just made up my mind. The ambient space $M$ does not matter that much, just enlarge it and contain $l^{2}$ is then alright.

Comment: "Actually the unedited answer by @Slup, the first part of his answer, may be what I am looking for. Note that in my question, certainly ‖‖ need no to be finite for every ∈. Rather, for those are finite,  collects them. " - that is precisely how I understood the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't now what is a precise meaning of *function space*. I think that what I have written below gives a counterexample you are seeking for $M$ being some abstract vector space (possibly algebraically isomorphic with some space of functions).

Let $D$ be any vector space with norm $||-||$ such that $(D,||-||)$ is not a Banach space. Let $(\overline{D}, ||-||')$ be a completion of $(D, ||-||)$. Then by Zorn's lemma we may write

$$\overline{D} = D \oplus C$$

for some linear subspace $C$ of $\overline{D}$ - decomposition as vector spaces but not as normed spaces. Now let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two distinct vector spaces with linear isomorphisms $\phi_1:C_1\rightarrow C$ and $\phi_2:C_2\rightarrow C$, respectively. Consider vector space

$$M = C_1 \oplus D \oplus C_2$$

Now we define two functions $||-||_1,||-||_2$ on $M$. For this pick $c_1\in C_1,\,d\in D, c_2\in C_2$ and define

$$||(c_1,d,c_2)||_1 = \begin{cases}||\phi_1(c_1) + d||' &\mbox{ if }c_2 = 0\\ +\infty &\mbox{ if } c_2\neq 0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$||(c_1,d,c_2)||_2 = \begin{cases}||d + \phi_2(c_2)||' &\mbox{ if }c_1 = 0\\ +\infty &\mbox{ if } c_1\neq 0
\end{cases}$$

Then $X =\{(c_1,d,0)\in M|c_1\in C_1,d\in D\} \subseteq M$ and $Y = \{(0,d,c_2)\in M|d\in D,c_2\in C_2\}\subseteq M$. Hence clearly $X \neq Y$.

**Edit** (thanks to indication of **Floris Claassens** in the comments below this answer).

If you want $||-||_1,||-||_2$ to be norms on $M$, then you can modify definitions as follows:

$$||(c_1,d,c_2)||_1 = ||\phi_1(c_1) + d||' + ||\phi_2(c_2)||'$$

$$||(c_1,d,c_2)||_2 = ||\phi_1(c_1)||' + ||d + \phi_2(c_2)||'$$

It does not change descriptions of $X, Y$ from the original, unedited answer.

**Further edit.**

In general if $X$ and $Y$ are complete, then they are both completions of $D$ with respect to the same (uniform structure) topology given by equivalent norms ${||-||_1}_{\mid D}$, ${||-||_2}_{\mid D}$ and hence by uniqueness of completion they must be abstractly isomorphic as normed spaces.

Comment: Interesting answer, unfortunately $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ are not norms as a norm is by definition a map from $M$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens to be honest I don't kow if this was OP's intention (maybe I misunderstood him - my english is poor), but I think I extended my example to cover also the case you mentioned.

Comment: The corrected version looks good. You should remove the first version of the 'norms', and move the norms in the edited section upward.

Comment: Given the OP stated he was considering two norms I assume using norms was his intention. That being said, with the modification this is a really good answer. Interesting to note though that in this case in some ways the spaces are still the same, as $\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$ given by $$\varphi((c_{1},d,0))=(0,d,\phi_{2}^{-1}(\phi_{1}(c_{1})))$$ is an isometric isomorphism. This is actually a very subtle question.

Comment: @Floris Classens Yes, you are right, that Op uses term norms. I got confused by his discussion of $X$ and $Y$ at the begining.

Comment: I rewrite the question, sorry for bringing about the confusion.