# Galerkin method and Schauder basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

While studying the books: *Monotone operators in Banach space and nonlinear partial differential equations from Showalter and Quelques méthodes de résolution des problèmes aux limites non linéaires from Lions*, in the part of nonlinear evolution equations (for example), they seem to assume that every separable reflexive Banach space has a Schauder basis.

In fact, in chapter 2 of Lions book, when dealing with the equation $$u'(t)+A(u(t))=0, u(0)=u_0,$$

for $u\in L^p((0,T),V)$, where $V$ is a separable reflexive Banach space, Lions use the Galerkin method and assume that there is a Schauder basis for $V$.

The same happen in Showalter's book, for example in Theorem 2.1 in the chapter 2 or in Theorem 4.1 in the chapter 3.

So my question is:

> Does every separable reflexive Banach space has a Schauder basis?

It may be the case that I am understanding it wrong, so if this is the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both books, it is not constructed a Schauder basis. In fact, they only assume the existence of a sequence $u_n\in V$ (linearly independent) such that $$\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Span}(\{u_1,\cdots, u_n\})}=V. \tag{1}$$

This sequence can be constructed, for example, by using the separability of $V$: let $v_n\in V$ be a dense sequence in $V$ and $V_n=\operatorname{Span}(\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\})$. Take $u_1,\cdots,u_{m_n}$ a basis of $V_n$ and note that the sequence $u_n$ is linearly independent and satisfies $(1)$.

Remark: Not every serapable reflexive Banach space has a Schauder basis. There is Enflo's [example](http://www.cnd.mcgill.ca/~ivan/PerEnfloAcounterexampleToTheApproximationProblemInBanachSpaces.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It may be useful

Comment: You are welcome @GiuseppeNegro. I was really confused by it and I thought that it would be good to share this information. I always thought that the sequence used in the Galerkin method was a Schauder basis, but now it is clear that there is nothing to with such a basis. However, by taking a look in the literature, when one has a Schauder basis, or other basis which are more refined, then it is possible to study some convergence properties of the aproximated solutions.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, I knew Enflo's example, but in my mind, it was not reflexive. Anyway in Triebel book of functions it is proved that most of the classical functions space has a Schauder basis.

Comment: In fact, for $V$ separable we can construct a linearly independent sequence $(u_n)$ in $V$ such that $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(\{u_1\})}=V$, which is better than $(1)$. [Proof here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60109/70305).