# Can a infinite dimensional Banach space have a dense Hamel basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hamel-basis

I'm looking for a link of a book or paper that has the following

**Theorem:**

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Then there exists a Hamel basis $B$ of $X$ that is dense in $X$ ( That is $\bar{B}=X$)

I found the theorem above in a textbook of functional analysis, but it only stated the theorem without proof or any other mentions. I've been searching for it for a while but i can't find it anywhere.
If someone knows where i can find it.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that Hamel basis of $C[a,b]$ can be dense in $C[a,b]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582954/is-it-true-that-hamel-basis-of-ca-b-can-be-dense-in-ca-b). the answer there has proof of that theorem

Comment: @MorA. Yes it has the theorem that i'm searching for ( Theorem 1 in the link )(I've posted a question asking for it), but there isn't any proof or mentions. I'm searching for the general case which is exactly the Theorem 1

Comment: The proof is right there in the answer