# Can $X \setminus Y$ be first category? For $Y$ a proper linear subspace of a completely metrizable TVS $X$

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, baire-category, first-countable

So I got $0$ credit on one of my school problems.  The comment was that if $Y$ is infinite dimensional, I cannot assume it has a countable basis. Hence I have absolutely no ideas how to solve this problem.  Please help so I can learn how to handle this type of scenario..

> Given $X$ a completely metrizable TVS, with proper linear subspace $Y$. Can $X \setminus Y$ be of first category? (Recall a set is of first category if it is the countable union of nowhere dense sets)

I will include my answer below, just to show my thought process...

---

$X$ is completely metrizable, so by Baire Category Theorem it cannot be the countable union of nowhere dense sets.  I will show that *every* proper linear subspace $Y$ is the countable union of nowhere dense sets, meaning $X\setminus Y$ *cannot* be first categroy. Otherwise $X=Y\cup (X \setminus Y)$ is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets, a contradiction

Assume that $Y\subseteq X$ is a finite dimensional, proper, linear subspace. Then I show that it is closed with empty interior, hence nowhere dense $(*)$

Then assume that $Y\subseteq X$ is an infinite dimensional, proper, linear subspace.  Since it is linear, it has a basis $Y = span\{ y_1, y_2, ... \}$.  Define the following sets for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$ S_n=span\{ y_1 , ..., y_n \} $$
Each $S_n$ is nowhere dense by $(*)$, and 
$$ Y = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n $$
Hence $Y$ is first category

Comment: Possibly some results [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60546/13130) could be of help in the Banach space setting, but I'm not sure what might be the case in the completely metrizable topological vector space setting.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've got is this, from the link in the comment of Dave L. Renfro.  Not sure yet how applicable it is, still have to think about it more

---

$X$ is completely metrizable, so by Baire Category Theorem it cannot be the countable union of nowhere dense sets.  I will show that *every* proper linear subspace $Y$ is nowhere dense sets, meaning $X\setminus Y$ *cannot* be first categroy. Otherwise $X=Y\cup (X \setminus Y)$ is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets, a contradiction

Given $Y$ a proper linear subspace of $X$, assume by contradiction that $Y$ is *not* nowhere dense.  Then it contains a non-empty open set $V$. Since $X$ is a TVS and continuous under addition, we can find a balanced open set $U$ contained in $V$ .  So far we have
$$ U \subseteq V \subseteq Y$$
Since $Y$ is linear, $tU \subseteq Y$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction to the fact that $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$. So $Y$ is nowhere dense