# Is it true that the intersection of two dense subspace of a linear normed space is also dense provided that one of them is of finite codimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $X_1,X_2$ be two dense subspace of $X,$ in [Is is true that the intersection of two dense subspaces of a linear normed space is also dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791981/is-is-true-that-the-intersection-of-two-dense-subspaces-of-a-linear-normed-space) it was showed by an example that $X_1\cap X_2$ is not necessarily dense in $X,$ but in that example $\mathrm{codim}X_1=\mathrm{codim}X_2=+\infty.$ So I wonder if $\mathrm{codim}X_1$ or $\mathrm{codim}X_2$ is finite, will the intersection $X_1\cap X_2$ be dense in $X$ ?

Comment: Take $f_1$ continuous and $f_2$ discontinuous linear functionals. Then $f_1+f_2$ and $f_2$ are dense of codimension 1 whose intersection is $\ker f_1$ closed of codimension 1.

Comment: @dsh You mean the **kernels** of $f_1+f_2$ and $f_2$. Nice example.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, I meant kernels. I guess I have seen this example before.

Comment: @dsh A nice example! Though the intersection should be $\ker f_1\cap\ker f_2$ actually...

Comment: @Tiffany Thank you for correction! I cannot modify comment, unfortunately.